# SUM(SUMIFS) to find multiple criteria in same row - not working

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a worksheet where I entered 'Test' in Column B.
I want to perform a =SUM(SUMIFS formula to find "Bear*" or "Dog*" (* b/c there could be text after)
in Column C, and add them together in the Row 'Test' + 1.
I then want to perform the same formula for Column D, E, G, H, I, J, and L

The below seemed to work, but the formula was funky.

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
  Dim Ws As Worksheet

For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  With Ws
     If .Index <> 1 Then
    
' find the last used row in Column A + 1
   Dim RngA As Long
      RngA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
'Add "Test" Name in Column B
    .Cells(RngA, "B").Value = "Test"

'Combine Data containing 'Bear*' or 'Dog*'
   Dim RngTest As Range
      Set RngTest = .Range("B:B").Find("Test", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    RngTest.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(C3:C, B3:B, {""BEAR*"" , ""DOG*""}))"
    RngTest.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(D3:D, B3:B, {""BEAR*"" , ""DOG*""}))"
    RngTest.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(E3:E, B3:B, {""BEAR*"" , ""DOG*""}))"
    RngTest.Offset(0, 5).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(G3:G, B3:B, {""BEAR*"" , ""DOG*""}))"
    RngTest.Offset(0, 6).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(H3:H, B3:B, {""BEAR*"" , ""DOG*""}))"
    RngTest.Offset(0, 7).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(I3:I, B3:B, {""BEAR*"" , ""DOG*""}))"
    RngTest.Offset(0, 8).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(J3:J, B3:B, {""BEAR*"" , ""DOG*""}))"
    RngTest.Offset(0, 10).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(L3:L, B3:B, {""BEAR*"" , ""DOG*""}))"

        End If
    End With
Next Ws
```

Comment: `C3:C` and `B3:B` are not viable range references in Excel.  You will need to use the ending row, or just use `C:C` and `B:B` respectively.

Comment: @BigBen Sorry!  the formula populates as: =SUM(SUMIFS($C:C, 'B3':(B), {"DRERYER'S*","EDY'S*"}))

Comment: @ScottCraner so: `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` and `RngTest.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(C3:C & LastRow, B3:B & LastRow, {""BEAR*"" , ""DOG*""}))"`  or just `RngTest.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(C:C, B:B, {""BEAR*"" , ""DOG*""}))"`?

Comment: `RngTest.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(C3:C" & LastRow & ", B3:B" & LastRow & ", {""BEAR*"" , ""DOG*""}))"`

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm still learning VBA coding.. why the `"` after the `C`, `&`, `B`?

Comment: @Parfait sorry, copy/paste error, I updated the formulas to the respective Columns